# How to initialize array before $scope will be loaded in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with my AngularJS application. In my html view, i have list that contains JavaScript objects.

```
<div ng-init="initWeek()" ng-controller="TableController">
<div id="TaskImages"> <div ng-repeat="task in taskList"> <div id="TaskImg" ><br>      {{task.title}}<br>{{task.start}} </div>   </div></div>
```

I set taskList by using the Jquery/Ajax, which gets all task object from server.

```
function getTaskFromServer() {

$.ajax({

    type : "POST",
    url : "main_page",

    success : function(data) {

        var taskList = $.parseJSON(data);

        week[0].push(taskList[0]);

    },

});
```

My controller looks like this:

```
$scope.initWeek = function() {

    getTaskFromServer();
};
$scope.taskList = week[currentlySelectedDay-1];
```

When I load application, the list "week" contains objects but in html view can see text.

I think that $scope.taskList is loaded before list "week".

For example, when I use:

```
$scope.initWeek = function() {

    getTaskFromServer();
    alert(week[0].lenght);
};
$scope.taskList = week[currentlySelectedDay-1];
```

Site displays alert and when i click Ok the text from taskList is a an website.

Comment: Thats how asynchronous operations work. You need to set `taskList` with a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an asynchronous operation, you must set the taskList inside the ajax callback:

```
function getTaskFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "main_page",
        success : function(data) {
            var taskList = $.parseJSON(data);
            week[0].push(taskList[0]);
            $scope.taskList = week[currentlySelectedDay-1];
        },
    }); 
}
```

It would be even better if you could replace the jquery ajax call with an angular call using $http.

Hope that helps.